# Script to show what transformation is being used in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

Does anyone know of a script that will search through a folder of MXDs (or an individual MXD) and report what coordinates system the data layers are in, what coordinate system the data frame/map extent is in, and if different state what transformation has been used (if any)?

Would really like to check content and whether correct transformations are being applied without having to open up every MXD for a project

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. If you look at the documentation, Layer objects do not have a transformation property -- `geographicTransformations` is a property of a [DataFrame](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm), There are tons of examples of code that iterates all the map documents in a folder; you'll need to compare the SpatialReference of the DataFrame with the SpatialReference of the dataSource of the Layer, and if not the same, then check the transformations in the DataFrame.